# GET Parameter not passed in Electron's loadURL function

Tags: javascript, php, get, electron

I want to pass GET Parameter from loadURL in Electron but it doesn't work

```
console.log("http://localhost/index.php?test=hallo");
mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost/index.php?test=hallo");
```

But on server side $_GET["test"] is not set. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

can't comment your question, cause my reputation is not enough.

i have tried on my local enviroment, and could get query string on server side from loadURL in Electron.

you could check does your server has received the request, and noticed that your server port is empty, did you forget or just 80.